# Spark Eclipse Import Package Error

Tags: eclipse, scala, shell, apache-spark

When I open shell in windows 10 and type spark-shell,it opens scala.After that I type

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
```

and it's ok on shell.There is no problem.

But when I try to run this command on eclipse it gives me error :

```
error: object apache is not a member of package org
   import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
```

Why it gives that error ? What should I do now ?

I make some research on internet,some say give the classpath etc..I tried everything but remain unsolvable.

Please help

Comment: If you are running on without maven, then you need to add the datanucleus and spark jar in reference library.

Comment: what is datanucleus ? Should I add all the jar folder under spark to the reference library ?

Comment: yeah..there are around 6 jars that need to be added.  datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar, datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar                       , spark-1.6.1.2.4.2.0-258-yarn-shuffle.jar                     
spark-assembly-1.6.1.2.4.2.0-258-hadoop2.7.1.2.4.2.0-258.jar 
spark-examples-1.6.1.2.4.2.0-258-hadoop2.7.1.2.4.2.0-258.jar

Comment: version can differ based on ur spark version

Comment: I already added datanucleus jars but how can i find yarn-shuffle jar,spark-assembly etc ? Can you write the correct names of them ? I am using spark 2.1.0.Thanks a lot.

Comment: All the jars are present in the spark folder itself. I gave the names based on spark version 1.6.1. No idea about spark 2.0.1. Need to check it once

Comment: I installed maven to eclipse and convert project to maven and then it resolved.Thank you Rajat